# Formatting a .csv file to print a table (C)

Tags: c

I have to print formatted table of csv file. I wonder if you know about any specific library or a tool that can help me with this - I just didn't find anything by googling.

this is the code and the code works fine, just have to print it like a formatted table. thanks!

```
void opportunity_table()
{
int i = 3;
char line[LINESIZE];
FILE* fp = fopen("opportunity_table.csv", "r");
if (!fp) {
    printf("File failed to open!\n");
    exit(1);
}
while (fgets(line, LINESIZE, fp)) {
    while (line[i] != '\n') {
        if (line[i] == ',') {
            printf("%s  ", "");
        }               
        else
            printf("%c", line[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    puts(" ");
}
}
```

the input I get from running this code is messy and look really bad.

Comment: You should show some sample input data, and the actual and expected results — those are important parts of an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Presumably, it is the _output_ and not the _input_ that yields the comment "the input I get from running this code is messy and looks really bad"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the width and precision fields of the `%s` specifier. The width field sets a width of at least the specified characters. The precision field will print up to the specified number of characters. Works as long as width is greater than precision.
`strpbrk` will give a pointer to the next character in the string or NULL.
The format string `"%*.*s"` will right justify the printing. Use `"%-*.*s"` to left justify.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WIDTH 7

int main( void) {
    char csv[] = "a,b,cde,fghij,i,jh\n";
    char *item = csv;
    char *comma = NULL;
    while ( *item && ( comma = strpbrk ( item, ",\n"))) {//pointer to each comma and the newline
        printf ( "%*.*s", WIDTH, comma - item, item);
        item = comma + 1;//skip the comma or newline
    }
    printf ( "\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If the width of the fields needs to vary, an array of widths could be used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void) {
    char csv[4][50] = {
        "a,b,cde,fghij,i,jh\n",
        "i,jk,lmno,pq,rst,uvw\n",
        "0,1,2,3456,78,9\n",
        "x,y,z,01,2345,6789\n"
    };
    char *item = NULL;
    char *comma = NULL;
    int width[] = { 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 5};
    int field = 0;
    for ( int loop = 0; loop < 4; ++loop) {
        field = 0;
        item = csv[loop];
        while ( *item && ( comma = strpbrk ( item, ",\n"))) {//pointer to each comma and the newline
            printf ( "%*.*s", width[field], comma - item, item);
            item = comma + 1;//skip the comma or newline
            field++;
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This could be customized by reading the file twice. The number of fields and the maximum width could be determined in the first read. Read the file the second time and print using the calculated widths.

Comment: Thanks alot, exactly what I needed!